# error on click of Submit Button in asp.net mvc page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I am in a strange problem. I have an asp.net mvc web page.

Scenario is like this:

Let's say user clicks on submit button once and page is postback to server. so far this is fine.

But if user keeps on clicking submit button continuously and the page is processing. my application crashes.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the button with javascript?

Comment: satjinder, you are right. that's the only way we can do that.